# Calculated field in tableau to find if the first row is Success or Failure

Tags: sql-server

I have the below data (from a table) with fields TransactionDate, UserID, and the StatusDesc. The goal is I want to show the userID, where the UserID does not have a login failure (indicated by statusDesc Column - 'Rejected') occurring prior on the same day as a successful login ( Sucessfull Login is indicated by statusDesc Column - 'Success').

**Actual DATA**

```
            TransactionDate                 UserId                      StatusDesc

            2018-12-02 00:00:01.957     Cesarmartinez1795@gmail.com     Rejected
            2018-12-02 00:00:14.907     Cesarmartinez1795@gmail.com     Success
            2018-13-02 00:00:22.390     Cesarmartinez1795@gmail.com     Success
            2018-13-02 00:00:28.610     Cesarmartinez1795@gmail.com     Rejected
            2018-14-02 00:00:22.390     ssunlife@gmail.com              Success
            2018-14-02 00:00:28.610     ssunlife@gmail.com              Rejected
```

**Expected Result**

```
            TransactionDate                 UserId                      StatusDesc
            2018-13-02 00:00:22.390     Cesarmartinez1795@gmail.com     Success
            2018-14-02 00:00:22.390     ssunlife@gmail.com              Success
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [LOD (Level of Detail) expression](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm) in a Calculated Field for this. LOD's can be tricky to wrap your head around at first, but once you've used them a few times they become very handy.

1. Create a new calculated field under Dimensions called "First Rejection of Day". This will have the timestamp of the first rejection of the day for the user, or null if there have been no rejections. Use the following code:

```html
{ FIXED [UserId], DATE([TransactionDate]) : MIN(
    IF [StatusDesc] = "Rejected" THEN
      [TransactionDate]
    END
  )
}
```

2. Create another calculated field called "Has Prior Rejection". Use the following code:

```html
ISNULL([First Rejection of Day]) = FALSE AND [First Rejection of Day] <= [TransactionDate]
```

3. Drag Has Prior Rejection to Filters, and select "False". This will filter out all records that have a prior rejection.

[Screenshot in Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPTBQ.png)

Comment: Thank you so much! this saved me a lot of time and glad I was able to learn something new. thanks again !